# Web fragments (Servlet API 3.0) - Also modular resources in WEB-INF directory

Tags: servlet-3.0, web-inf

According to Servlet 3.0, a JAR placed in WEB-INF/lib has static content from its META-INF/resource directory accessible from the web-context root.

The specification doesn't say anything about modular resources, which should be accessible from the WEB-INF directory. 
I would like to create a modular project, where every module "adds" all files from its WEB-INF directory to the web-context/WEB-INF directory. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I understand.. Simply create a folder META-INF/resources/WEB-INF :)